# Nested function calls and missing input parameter, python

Tags: python, function-calls, function-call

I'm trying out some Text Classification tutorials [here](https://github.com/abromberg/sentiment_analysis_python/blob/master/sentiment_analysis.py):

I don't understand the function calls in line 59 -- 65:

```
#creates a feature selection mechanism that uses all words
def make_full_dict(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words])

#tries using all words as the feature selection mechanism
print 'using all words as features'
evaluate_features(make_full_dict)
```

Shouldn't `make_full_dict` be called with a string input value for `words`?

Comment: It looks like `evaluate_features` is attempting to evaluate functions and mostly likely uses that function and calls it with certain parameters. It would be helpful to post the definition of `evaluate_features` to be sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further context, it is a bit difficult to give a complete answer to your question. It seems that the `evaluate_features` method takes a function as parameter; in that case, you don't need to call the function which was passed in as a parameter. Only `evaluate_features` should do that. If you call the function, then the return value of the function is what `evaluate_features` will get, rather than the function itself

If you want to see what that function is doing, add some print statements in the `make_full_dict` method which will help you see what words were passed to it

Comment: Thanks @khredos, the point you made about passing "make_full_dict" return value vs the function itself makes a lot of sense. Cheers.